# How do I ALTER a PostgreSQL table and make a column unique?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

I have a table in PostgreSQL where the schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "foo_table" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "permalink" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "text" varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
)
```

Now I want to make the permalink unique across the table by `ALTER`-ing the table.

Comment: `create unique index on foo_table (permalink)`

Answer (score 431, accepted):

I figured it out from the PostgreSQL docs, the exact syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE the_table ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (thecolumn);
```

Thanks [Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55774/frederik-gheysels).

Comment: In case you need to reverse this.
`ALTER TABLE the_table DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS constraint_name;`

Answer (score 372):

Or, have the DB automatically assign a constraint name using:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD UNIQUE (thecolumn);
```

Comment: If you do this, postgres is going to create the constraint but is the name is going to "automatically" assign is the word "add".
I have just tried it

Comment: When I use the syntax above, Postgress creates the new contraint with the name `mytable_mycolumn_key`  I'm quite happy with that :-)

Answer (score 64):

it's also possible to create a unique constraint of more than 1 column:

```
ALTER TABLE the_table 
    ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column1, column2);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for something like:
      `ALTER TABLE actions
        ADD CONSTRAINT actions_unique_constraint UNIQUE (payload::text, name);` or `ALTER TABLE actions
        ADD CONSTRAINT actions_unique_constraint UNIQUE ((payload::text), name);`

Answer (score 7):

Try the following

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE (column_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

To make a column unique in a PostgreSQL table, you can use the `ALTER TABLE` statement with the `ADD CONSTRAINT` clause.

Here's an example SQL statement

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_column_name UNIQUE (column_name);
```

In above statement, mytable is the name of the table you want to modify, `column_name` is the name of the column you want to make unique, and `unique_column_name` is a name you choose for the unique constraint.

If there are already duplicate values in the column you want to make unique, the `ALTER TABLE` statement will fail. You will need to remove or modify the duplicates before you can add the unique constraint.

Also, keep in mind that making a column unique will create an index on that column, which can impact performance if the table is very large or the column is frequently updated.