# How to change PRIMARY KEY into UNIQUE KEY when FKs reference it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following two columns:

```
`MainTable`
barcode (PK)
name
```

I then have another table that FKs to it:

```
`SubTable`
barcode (FK)
info
```

How would I add an auto-incrementing Primary Key to the MainTable field, while ensuring barcode uniqueness? Essentially, how would I do the following without a FK error arising?

```
alter table maintable drop primary key;
alter table maintable add unique key (barcode);
ALTER TABLE `maintable` ADD `id` INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: Wait.... Why would you want to do this? What's the benefit to adding the auto int and replacing the natural key with it?

Comment: Sound really weird. But SQL looks like the correct approach on first view. Only one part is missing: Update of old data so entry 10000445 is not getting #1

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly you want to add a unique constraint to your barcode column on your main table?  If so this is a duplicate question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469471/how-do-i-alter-a-postgresql-table-and-make-a-column-unique

Comment: @theDarse no -- barcode **already** is a PK.

Comment: @Zane -- the database and needs have changed, so the barcode is changed from an int(11) to a very-long string, and isn't the best for joining on it. We don't have control of what the barcode contains.

Comment: Also the mere fact that the barcodes CAN change indicates a need for a surrogate key.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE mainTable DROP CONSTRAINT Primary_key
ALTER TABLE maintable ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (barcode)
ALTER TABLE maintable ADD COLUMN Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
```

This would add your new primary key, then you would need to add a new column to the sub table referencing the new primary key as a FK, and drop the old Fk out out the sub table

Comment: @David542 - Nothing in MySQL.

Comment: yeah my mistake should be Auto_increment in mysql sorry about that