# Insert large TEXT data into postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `metadata` which has a column called `data` of type `TEXT`. There are currently about 10 million rows in the `metadata` table.

I want to `insert` additional rows into the `metadata` table but I need to ensure that no two rows have the same content in `data` field(no duplicate data). **The content of each data field is about 100 to 1000 lines long string i.e. extremely large strings.**

What is the best way to insert a new row while ensuring that there are no duplicates in a performant manner?

Comment: add a unique constraint on that column

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469553/4982088) answer.

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be happy with the performance of such validation. If you have no other field (e.g. id), you have to create an unique constraint on the column `data`, as suggested by @mike.k

Comment: @JimJones, what would be ways to improve the performance? Could you please explain the reasons why the performance will be affected or point me to some useful resource? :)

Comment: @raqib could you add some samples of this metadata table to your question? If there is no other way to uniquely identify the records, you have no other choice than create a PK using the `data` field. The inserts will be slow because the database was to look for a string match on the whole table in order to tell if the record already exists or not. A numerical comparison, for example, is much more efficient.. that's why I asked if there was any way add an id to the records.